# Make mobile Navbar disappear - PRO's

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

Important: Please read until the end !!!

Hey. I'm building a responsive single-page. There is a Bootstrap navbar on top with some anchor links. 
What I look for: When it's in the mobile view with the "hamburger", and the user clicks on the hamburger so the anchors show up, and he clicks on one of the anchor links, it's scrolling great, but the menu does not close automatically. It stays open until you manually close it again by clicking on the hamburger.

I already found a solution, but it has a problem! 
This code solved the problem great so far (function-wise), but has a visual bug:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){$(".navbar-toggle").click() //bootstrap 3.x});
```

The Problem: It affects the site visually negative in non-mobile, desktop mode. All the words in the navbar like "About Me", "Contact" etc. disappear like wiped out, just for a half second, and then are back in. So everything works, but it's not looking nice. Is there a code fix to make this solve? I'm a total beginner, thats the problem in this case I dont know a lot about it yet and dont understand JS, just copied the code. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

JS

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: My friend it works totally fine, thanks a lot you saved my life. Unfortunately I dont have 15 or more reputation points I'd like to do any upvote instead of that green arrow but if I get it I'll do!!